# get selected item text when it's changed in a drop down combo box

Tags: winapi

I crated a simple drop-down combo box with two items, which is a child window on a toolbar.
When an item is selected, I would like to get the text of the selected item. I used Spy++ on the Combo box and I didn't find useful message to do this. So I treat the message CBN_SELCHANGE for the window procedure of toolbar. It looks like:

```
if (CBN_SELCHANGE == HIWORD(wParam))
    GetText(....)
```

But the problem is: Suppose the two items are "first" and "second", and "first" is already selected.
When I select "second", the text gotten by GetText is still"first". I found it's too early to call GetText at the point the CBN_SELCHANGE message occurs. But I can't find a good point to call GetText.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling `GetWindowText` use the message [CB_GETLBTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after ascertaining the current selection (e.g. using [CB_GETCURSEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).